# jQuery - Passing only certain values into a running total

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which passes 20 values into the variable `total` as a running total:

```
total += parseInt($(this).html(),10);
```

How could I achieve the same but only for the 5th, 10th and 15th values of the 20 being passed in?

EDIT:

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function()
    {
        total += parseInt($(this).html(),10);
    });
```

Comment: What is `this`? Why did you delete your other question?

Comment: `$this` is 20 numbers/ values, that's it.

Comment: how is the element formatted? How are the numbers arranged in `this`?

Comment: Is this from inside of a loop?

Comment: Are the numbers comma delineated? Can you show the string in your question?

Comment: Not from inside a loop.

Comment: It doesn’t really make sense for `$(this)` to be 20 values, so please actually add context, because it’s important.

Comment: Updated, not sure what else you need?

Comment: FYI, from your update, the answer to "is this from inside a loop?" was "yes."

Comment: Apols, it has been a long long day and I'm struggling like hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume your full code looks something like:

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function (idx) {
    total += parseInt($(this).html(),10);
});
```

What you'll need to do is use the mod operator like so:

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function (idx) {
    if ((idx + 1) % 5 === 0 && idx !== 19)) {
        total += parseInt($(this).html(),10);
    }
});
```

Every 5th value apart from 20th. Note the `+ 1` and the `19` because the it's zero indexed.

Another way to do this with arbitrary values would be like so:

```
$('#table1 .set2').each(function (idx) {
    if ([4, 9, 14].indexOf(idx) !== -1) {//5th, 10th and 15th
        total += parseInt($(this).html(),10);
    }
});
```

Edited to make code easier to read.(Using if rather than ternary operator)

Comment: Appreciate that, what if I need any combination of the 20, for example, 1st, 3rd, 8th, 12th etc.

Comment: You can put anything into the if statement so for instance if you wanted the 1st, 3rd, 8th and 12th, you could change the if statement to `if (idx === 0 || idx === 2 || idx === 7 || idx === 11) {`

Comment: The reason I used mod to answer your question is because the 5th, 10th and 15th values are multiples of 5.